# Google authentication and iframes

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

### Background

I have an existing Python-based Google AppEngine app with a few pages for which login:required is set in app.yaml.

I'd like to be able to put this app in an iframe. However, whenever the user navigates to a page that requires login and the user is redirected to the Google login page, the iframe goes blank as the login page sets the x-frame-options:DENY header option.

### Questions

Is there a way to make the Google authentication use a pop-up (like FaceBooks and Twitters authentication schemes does?)?

ALternatively, is it possible to catch the login required event, and redirect to another page that I supply, that does some iframe breakout and then redirects to the real login page?

auth_fail_action does not support a custom redirect URL, is there another way?

The only other solution I can think of is not to use login: required, but to reimplement the same logic in each view (or in a decorator). However, as this is rather clumsy and requires lots of rewriting I'd rather not go this route.

Thanks in advance,
Egil

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately No.

Depending on your specific needs, you could make a passthrough URL on your app that handles the `login: required` portion before loading the page that iframes your app.

Something akin to this:

**app.yaml**

```
handlers:
- url: /login-check
  script: main.app
  login: required
```

**main.py**

```
import webapp2

class LoginCheckHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # If they get here, they have been authorized via google's login page
        webapp2.redirect(self.request.get('redirect_url'), abort=True)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/login-check', LoginCheckHandler),
], debug=True)
```

Now you can load your main page via `$APPENGINE_HOST/login-check?redirect_url=$REAL_PAGE_URL` and it will ensure the user is logged in first and then redirect them to `$REAL_PAGE_URL` which can now iframe your app engine page.